# how to create dataframe from json input file in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating dataframe from downloaded json file which results in error that some of data is corrupted.
i used spark.read.json("json file path") to create dataframe. Error is like:
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:
Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, val df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).cache() and then
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't specify the error you have, I assume you see something similar to what i see:

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, val df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).cache() and then
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().
```

To fix it you need to use command like:

```
spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("json file path")
```

Here is an example:

```
cat /Users/yuri/test.json 
{
    "name": "Yuri",
    "gender": "male"
}
```

Here is the pyspark code:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/Users/yuri/test.json")
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the output:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+------+----+
|gender|name|
+------+----+
|male  |Yuri|
+------+----+
```